Birkat kohanim on Shabbat in South Africa
A South African acquaintance of mine told me that in (the Ashkenazi communities in) South Africa, the custom is not to do birkat kohanim on Shabbat, even when Yom Tov falls on Shabbat. He said that there was some controversy when a synagogue tried to say birkat kohanim on a Shabbat, and they ended up being overruled. He didn't know any of the details, and some Googling hasn't brought anything up (that I could find).
I'm aware of an older practice to omit birkat kohanim on Shabbat (see this question), but I don't know of the recent history of the practice, say in the last 100 years. Does anyone know about the recent history (and current state) of this practice, any explicit reasoning behind current implementations, and anything specific about South Africa or about a controversy?

As far as I remember, the custom not to do birchas kohanim on Shabbat yomotov is to do with marital relations and Mikvah, although I can't remember all the details

Does this answer your question? How did the “custom” of not duchaning on Yom Tov that falls on Shabbos arise

@sabbahillel That question is linked in the OP.
